# std::launder, std::vector and move constructible only types

Tags: c++, constants, c++17

For a [feature request](https://github.com/skypjack/entt/issues/172) of [a project of mine](https://github.com/skypjack/entt) , I thought/I've been suggested to use `std::launder` to move elements around in a vector where the elements are move constructible only (no move assignment operator defined).
The goal is to move the last element to a given position `i`, then pop the former.

In other terms, the resulting code would be something like this (simplified version for the purpose):

```
void foo(std::vector<my_type> &vec, std::size_t i) {
    my_type *el = vec.data() + i;
    el->~my_type();
    new (std::launder(el)) my_type{std::move(vec.back())};
    vec.pop_back();
}
```

Where `my_type` is defined as:

```
struct my_type { const int v; };
```

The purpose of using `std::launder` is to set a barrier against the possible optimization due to the fact that `v` within `my_type` is `const`. Therefore to be able to recycle the memory reserved for `vec[i]` so as to replace the contained object with a different instance (actually, I'm theoretically *moving* the last item to a different position).

Is this a valid approach/solution or is this still UB, as it would happen if I did something similar without recurring to `std::launder`?

As far as I understood it, the purpose of `std::launder` is to allow users to do things like this one and thus it seems to me that the above snippet is legal. But I wouldn't be surprised if I was wrong, so I'd like to have a feedback by someone more experienced than me

--- **EDIT**

Similarly I want also to *swap* to elements of the same type.
The resulting code should be something like this:

```
const auto tmp = std::move(vec[i]);
vec[i].~object_type();
new (std::launder(&vec[i])) object_type{std::move(vec[j])};
vec[j].~object_type();
new (std::launder(&vec[j])) object_type{std::move(tmp)};
```

I'm quite confident that if `std::launder` fits with the first example, this one should work as well for similar reasons. Am I wrong?

Comment: For containers whose elements contain const/reference members, there are some [issues](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0532r0.pdf) not been solved yet, so currently it is hard to say there is a standard way to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`launder` gets you a pointer to an object that's already there.

There's no object there. You just destroyed it in the previous line.

Even the call to `launder` itself is pure unadulterated UB.

For this kind of thing, `launder` is needed when you *access* the newly created object. Not when you create it.

Comment: It makes sense. May I ask you how can I move then the last instance to position `i` if `T` isn't trivially destructible and `T` isn't move assignable if possible?